# Tick/Untick check box/radio button/toggle button from the keyboard

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm looking for a way to uncheck the selected check box/radio button/toggle button using the keyboard in Windows 7, preferably in XP and Vista as well. I know you can use the Space bar to toggle the state of the currently selected button, but is there a way to set a control to ticked or unticked without risk of toggling it if is is already in the desired state?

Comment: If they are in the desired state, why would you want to tick/untick?

Comment: djerry certainly has a point. However, I don't believe there is a way to specifically "uncheck" (or "check") a checkbox/radio button regardless of its current state, unless the software provides this functionality (eg. a "select all" option perhaps)

Comment: @djerry, I think what LodSfo is looking for is a way to ensure that the control is set to the desired state. Where spacebar always toggles, is there a way to initiate a "check" or "uncheck" command directly? I just submitted an edit to that effect to clarify it.

Answer (score 43):

Use the Tab key or the mouse to select the check box and then press space bar key

Comment: This worked in Windows 7.

Comment: Bonus: hold shift and press tab, you can select the previous check box.

Comment: -1, has nothing to do with the question. LodSfo already nows pressing space, so he will now how to reach it.

Comment: Works on Ubuntu as well

Comment: +1, This works in Chromium web browser and Firefox as well.

Answer (score 10):

To check/uncheck a checkbox (tested in Windows 7):

<kbd>+</kbd> to check
<kbd>-</kbd> to clear

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Google Chrome, version 43.0.2357.130 on Windows 7.

Comment: not working on Windows XP, tested inside Virtualbox, using a notebook (also tested with activated numpad emulation)

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to control this for sure.

There are underlying controls that have default behaviors in Windows forms.  Factors such as if these controls are a part of a control group will also have an affect on the outcome.

Also, there is no way to know how a developer handles certain events based on control selection and changes.